# JQuery Load() reloading whole body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using a nimbb api to record video using a webcam and the project is very simple.Here is my [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/27PpL/). Once i finish recording i get this message "Your video has been saved. Thank you!". I want to skip this message and reload the div so that webcam loads again. I am doing like this.

```
            var url ="index.html";

            //alert("yes");
            alert("Your video has been saved. Thank you!");


            $("#re").load(url);
```

But this is reloading whole body. I just want to load webcam div. What i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `load()` you can target css selectors within the page being loaded. If your div has `id="video"` for example:

```
$("#re").load(url + ' #video');
```

be sure to leave a space between the url and the selector

See **loading page fragments** section of **[load() API docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**

Comment: well i dont have #video id but i do have scipt like <object id="nimbb"... /> and i tried $("#re").load(url + ' #re'); which seems to be working. Is this a good approach?

Comment: will end up with duplicate ID, could try `#nimbb`